# How to remove Passenger standalone?

Tags: apache2, passenger

I'm building a new laptop for development and had installed the following over the last few days:

- Ubuntu 11.04
- Apache2
- RVM
- Ruby 1.9.2 under rvm
- Ruby 1.8.7 under rvm
- Passenger3 at 1.9.2@global
- Passenger module for Apache using Ruby 1.9.2
- Passenger3 at 1.8.7@global

I was about to set up some reverse proxy to Passenger standalone using Ruby 1.8.7 when I accidentally typed in Passenger start in a terminal window which did not point to 1.8.7@global.

The next thing I knew Passenger decided to install Nginx and itself without even a 'by your leave' and now I have an extra Passenger standalone installed somewhere on the machine that I want to get rid of but I can't find any instructions on how to remove this.

### Edit

I have found a .passenger directory under /home/purvez

Maybe it's that one that I need to get rid of.  Can anyone confirm or deny this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working with the same problem on Mac OS X 10.7.3

I also found the ~/.passenger/standalone directory under my users home directory with two directories under that, one of which was this one:

3.0.11-universal-ruby1.8.7-x86_64-macosx-10.7

The other directory was passenger standalone for Ruby 1.9.3 which is the one I wanted and was created from a previous run.

I moved the "3.0.11-universal-ruby1.8.7-x86_64-macosx-10.7" directory to a new name to test and see if another run of "passenger start" would yield the same result and it did. The binaries were installed again under the same directory name and the console messages were the same during the second install. I did expect this but this confirms that passenger thought the binaries were not installed, so I have removed the directory and moved on.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a play with this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the User Guide that was installed to my system:

> To uninstall Phusion Passenger, please first remove all Phusion
>   Passenger configuration directives from your Nginx configuration
>   file(s). After you've done this, you need to remove the Phusion
>   Passenger files.
>
> - If you installed Phusion Passenger via a gem, then type `gem uninstall passenger`.   You might have to run this as root.
> - If you installed Phusion Passenger via a source tarball, then remove the directory   in which you placed the extracted Phusion Passenger
>     files. This directory is the   same as the one pointed to the by
>     'PassengerRoot' configuration directive.

I did an rm -rf on /var/lib/passenger-standalone, rebooted, and all seems well now.