# How to completely uninstall phusion passenger in Ubuntu 13.10, Apache2 combination?

Tags: passenger

I installed the Phusion Passenger using the below commands

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates
```

Then, because of some reason, I tried to uninstall Phusion Passenger by the following way,
First: I removed the all Phusion Passenger configuration directives
Than: `gem uninstall passenger`

```
(results: gem "passenger" is not installed)
```

If I put "`passenger -v`". It returns

```
Phusion Passenger version 4.0.37
"Phusion Passenger" is a trademark of Hongli Lai & Ninh Bui.
```

Still it is not completely removed. I don't know how to proceed further.

I want to completely remove the Phusion Passenger, and install the fresh copy. Please assist me to do this

Comment: Read this http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#uninstalling, which is not very hard to find. Uninstalling through the same tool you used to install (so use apt-get)

Comment: They didn't gave any procedure to uninstall through APT

Comment: I was actually installed through APT

Comment: So you ran sudo apt-get uninstall PACKAGE NAME

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get uninstall libapache2-mod-passenger. It through error like this : Invalid operation uninstall

Comment: from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832505/how-to-remove-passenger-standalone
"If you installed Phusion Passenger via a gem, then type gem uninstall passenger. You might have to run this as root.
If you installed Phusion Passenger via a source tarball, then remove the directory in which you placed the extracted Phusion Passenger files. This directory is the same as the one pointed to the by 'PassengerRoot' configuration directive."

Comment: I tried both the ways. but understand dude.I was installed through APT.

Comment: It's `apt-get remove`, not `apt-get uninstall`. Pass the same package name that you passed to `apt-get install`.

Comment: I find out the answer dude.."sudo apt-get purge passenger"

Comment: I obvious made a mistake, it is not 'uninstall', I had one of those moments it is remove.

Comment: Ok diek..I really thanks for interested in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A friend had the same problem:

- `apt-get remove passenger` gave "passenger is not installed"
- `gem uninstall passenger` gave "passenger is not installed"
- `passenger -v` shows it is installed

The reason is that she had installed passenger with Ruby 1.9.1 and since upgraded to Ruby 2.1.5. (note: rvm was not installed).

The answer is to `gem1.9.1 uninstall passenger` which prompts if you want to remove the gem and packages or just the gem.

Answer (score 3):

should be able to run:

apt-get purge  (I used passenger)

I hope this helps!

Comment: As should apt-get remove, but remove won't touch related configuration files, purge deletes some of them (which are not at home dir).